# Country tag design

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging

I saw at the SO site some icons for the tags (like [asp.net-mvc](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc)).
May be we can add country flags for its badge? It will add some colors to tags and questions will be easy to read.

---

Update: What size shall we use for the country flag in tag wiki.

Comment: i like this! I know it's normally done for sponsors, but if we can adapt it for travel.se it would be super cool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are sponsored tags (FAQ: [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)). Putting icons on unsponsored tags [has been requested before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65916/free-logo-on-tags-of-open-source-developments-until-theyre-filled-by-paid-logos) and declined.

OTOH, it's fine to add flags to the tag wikis for countries, so please do so!

More info about sponsored tags [can be found here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags+advertising+or+sponsored-tags+or+sponsorship?sort=votes).

Comment: Looks good for the USA tag, not sure the France one works as well. Maybe they need a framing background? Anyway, tag wiki edits submitted for the flag for these two, please accept if appropriate or give feedback on the correct way to add the flags if not!

Comment: Updated the Russian flag - the smaller one.

Comment: @Dori I think yours looks better too! Shall we recommend roughly 100x50 then?

Comment: Or we could get countries to sponsor their tags. Anyone here a king or president? (-;

Comment: The declined proposal is about having icons about open source projects on their respective tags as long as nobody pays for them. That still is promotion, and so sponsoring. What is being asked here is in a totally different ballpark. It's not that you're promoting a country by putting their flag on a tag.